# Is it possible to checkout with 2 different shipping options on a single order?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

This is regarding a marketplace in WooCommerce that has different vendors. Let's say you are buying item A from Vendor 1 and item B from Vendor 2. And you would like to get the first item shipped to your home, but you want to pick up Item B, since it's close to your home. Is it possible to checkout on a single order choosing a shipping method for item A and a different one for item B?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would suggest doing this programmatically, but honestly try this [plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-advanced-shipping-packages/#:%7E:text=Split%20your%20cart%20into%20separate,rates%20based%20on%20your%20setup.)

If you want to go the code route checkout this  [article](https://www.xadapter.com/woocommerce-split-cart-items-order-ship-via-multiple-shipping-methods/)

Comment: Thank you LakesLIT, I will try the code!